# SQLALCHEMY how sum fields?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, sum

I have the following query

```
  SELECT partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego,
sum(partediariolote.solidoPartediariolote),
                            sum(partediariolote.liquidoPartediariolote)
                            FROM tecnoredDB.partediariolote
                            INNER JOIN partediarioriego
                            ON partediarioriego.idPartediarioriego = partediariolote.idPartediarioriego
                            WHERE idPlanta=5
                            GROUP BY partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego;
```

I am trying to do this query via alchemy, but the result is not summed, this is the query I am trying with.

```
db.session.query(Partediariolote,func.sum(Partediariolote.solidoPartediariolote).label('solido'),func.sum(Partediariolote.liquidoPartediariolote).label('liquido'),Partediarioriego).join(Partediarioriego, Partediarioriego.idPartediarioriego == Partediariolote.idPartediarioriego).filter(Partediarioriego.idPlanta == idplanta_session).filter(Partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego.between(desde,hasta)).group_by(Partediarioriego,Partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego).all()
```

Comment: there is a date range filter in the query string, but not the displayed sql query - why? try reducing complexity to get it working, then add back the wanted filters 1 at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to `sqlalchemy` query does not quite correspond to the `SQL` version, where the key difference is that the `SQL` version groups by just one column `partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego`, whereas the `sqlalchemy` version actually incudes all columns of the `Partediariolote` model. Below should be much closer to the original:

```
db.session.query(
    # Partediariolote,  # REMOVE THIS
    Partediariolote.fechaPartediarioriego,  # USE this instead
    func.sum(Partediariolote.solidoPartediariolote).label("solido"),
    func.sum(Partediariolote.liquidoPartediariolote).label("liquido"),
    Partediarioriego,
).join(
    Partediarioriego,
    Partediarioriego.idPartediarioriego == Partediariolote.idPartediarioriego,
).filter(
    Partediarioriego.idPlanta == idplanta_session
).filter(
    Partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego.between(desde, hasta)
).group_by(
    # Partediarioriego,  # REMOVE THIS
    Partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego,
).all()
```